# When iterating over a dictionary in python, why do you get the key and not the key-value tuple?

Tags: python

When I'm running this:

```
dic = {"key1": 1, "key2": 2}
for item in dic:
    print(f'{type(item)}: {item}')
```

I was expecting to iterate over the key-value tuple, but learned that for this I need to iterate over `dic.items()`

The same is when `list(dic)` is called, which is consistent of course. 
So what is it in the dictionary that makes its iterable be the keys?
Why is that, or rather, how can I understand that from the dictionary documentation?

The best I could find in the docs is

> Unlike sequences, which are indexed by a range of numbers,
>   dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any immutable type;
>   strings and numbers can always be keys

Is that it? but what does it mean, is the "indexed by" means that this will be the dictionary iterable?

Comment: Because that's what the language designers decided. It makes sense in the context of e.g. `in`, where you're looking for whether that key is in the dictionary, rather than a key-value pair (you likely don't yet know the value). As to how you can determine it from the docs, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping.

Comment: It would be even weirder if the behavior between lists and dicts was inconsistent, where one produces a 1-dimensional iterable of elements, and the other produces a 2-dimensional iterable of tuples. Behavior should be consistent, and using keys made more sense than using values.

Comment: While this is a good question, I would suggest it is deleted as being off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a `for` loop does is essentially calling `iter()` with the expression after `in` (this creates an [iterator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator) of the dictionary) and in each iteration, calling `next()` with the iterator to get the next element.

Let's look at what `iter(dict)` does on [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).

> **`iter(d)`**
>
> Return an iterator over the keys of the dictionary. This is a shortcut for `iter(d.keys())`.

As to why the designers designed it this way, you'd have to ask *them*. My first instinct was that `iter(dict)` should return an iterator of KVPs, but that's just me...

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. I wasn't trying to contest the reasoning for doing that (being consistent with other things that iterates makes total sense), but this helped me find the answers in the docs (for returns iter, which in turn returns key when iterating over a dictionary)