# Applying dict() on list of dicts returned unexpected value. How dict() Works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.8

**Python 3.8.6**

I have a list of dicts that have similar keys. Like this one:

```py
data = [
  {
    'type': 
    'individual', 'details': {}
  }, 
  {
    'type': 'personal', 
    'details': {}
  }
]
```

It was unexpected that `dict(data)` returned `{'type': 'details'}`.
I supposed this code should return an exception, but it didn't.

What happening there?
Why Python suppose this is correct behavior?
Are there any useful examples of such behavior?

Comment: [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) accepts (among other options) an iterable of key-value pairs. A list of dictionaries with two keys each meets that requirement.

Comment: Why did you expect it to raise an exception? Did you try looking at the documentation?

Comment: I reasonable way to understand this from `dict()`'s perspective is to look at `list(data[0])` or `[list(d) for d in data]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obscure use of one of the ways that dict() can be called.

> Otherwise, the positional argument must be an iterable object.
> Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two
> objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new
> dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value. If a key
> occurs more than once, the last value for that key becomes the
> corresponding value in the new dictionary.

[Source](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/dict.html)

Iterating over a dictionary gives you its keys, so unintentionally your argument perfectly matches the requirements.

No one would ever call `dict()` in the way you just did.  Calling something like `dict(enumerate(my_list))` is a more interesting use case.

Comment: Wow it really makes sense now. However, I'm still surprised that you can unpack dictionary to keys like ```key_one, key_two = data[0]```. Why it unpack to keys, not to tuples of (key, value) ? Because of iterating by keys?

Comment: @inyutin.  That's one of the post common mistakes I make when writing python.  I repeatedly write `for a, b in my_dict` rather than `for a, b in my_dict.items()`.  I don't know why the Python gods decided that iterating over a dictionary meant iterating over its keys, but that's what it does.

Comment: Yes, no one should use code like this. However, I have a service that validate requests by pydantic. Model specifies that in should accept ```dict```. However, another service send ```list``` by mistake and I was confused that there were no errors.

Comment: @inyutin you can do `dict([d.items() for d in data])`...

Comment: @inyutin see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59270856/3001761